# Why won't spingboot connect to the mongodb server and instead give me a socket error?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a springboot application and I'm using mongoDB as the database. I have all the proper dependencies in my pom.xml file but upon running my application, I get the following error:

> ```
> com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:535) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:585) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:666) ~[na:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
>   ... 4 common frames omitted
> ```

However the program still runs but upon running my the program in Postman or Talend API, I get a 404 not found error.

The exact same code is working for my colleagues so i'm sure it's not an issue at the code thus why I haven't provided the code. I will provide the code if necessary for analysis.

I tried a bunch of things like changing the springboot version from 3.0.3 to 2.7.4, re-writing the code, changing the server port but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pointing to same database as your colleagues ?

Step 1: Please validate ,if you have mongodb properties specified in application properties or yml file. Below is sample , you can check your colleagues properties file & compare

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=YourDBName
```

Step 2: Based on OS type , see if your port is free windows(task manager)/mac (activity monitor).

Step 3: If port is free, see if you can connect to mongo db through mongo db client using your credentials .Otherwise add your colleagues's credentials  in code & see if you can connect.